# Is there pre-defined operators for raylib's Vector2 in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, operator-overloading, raylib

[image: Error]

Are these operators pre-defined or am I doing something wrong?
I did try to compile but also gave same error.
By the way, same is happenning with all Vector2 ops.:(
Here is the code:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(800, 450, "raylib [core] example - basic window");
    SetWindowState(FLAG_VSYNC_HINT);
    while (!WindowShouldClose()){
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawFPS(10,10);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}        

class Particle {
    public:
        Vector2 pos;
        Vector2 vel;
        Vector2 acc;
        void Update() {
            vel += acc;
            pos += vel;
            acc -= acc;
        }
        void Show(Color c) {
            DrawCircle(pos.x,pos.y,5,c);
        }

};
```

Comment: [This documentation](https://robloach.github.io/raylib-cpp/classraylib_1_1_vector2.html) says `-=` should work, but since you're subtracting the vector from itself you might just want to assign `Vector2::Zero()` to it instead.

Comment: Exactly @RetiredNinja, That's Why I think it's strange that it's doing this.

Comment: If not, then could i get it thru vcpkg

Comment: I assumed since you didn't mention issues with `+=` that you were using the C++ version already and only missing `-=`.  Important to mention all errors.

Comment: Sorry about that!@RetiredNinja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator overloading is a C++ feature, which is added by [raylib-cpp](https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp), while [raylib](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib) itself is a C library, and C doesn't support operator overloading.

[Raylib-cpp](https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp) is a header-only library, you only need to download it and put its `#include` directory somewhere inside your project and tell the compiler to add this `#include` directory to your project's include directories.